# Installing Ubuntu 14 from USB on Fresh Drive on HP Mini 110 says Missing Bootmgr

Tags: usb, software-installation, drive

I made a USB stick of Ubuntu 14 using unetbootin. I did it from Windows 7. When I tried to boot the stick on the fresh new hard drive in my hp mini 110, it would not boot, and said a bootmgr was not present. What do I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used LinuxLive USB Creator to do so successfully many times. You can try too from downloading- http://www.linuxliveusb.com/download . It's free and Win 7 compatible.
You need to format again the usb stick and make it bootable with this LiLi again.

Comment: Yes, thank you for answering! I discovered that program later on and it worked so quick and easy! Installing Ubuntu 14 was a breeze after that; even the WiFi took care of itself! Then I discovered the programming platforms.....very pleased!

Comment: Thanks Donx, If the question is solved, plz mark it as answered!